# Is there a way to have Amazon Code Whisperer auto-enable in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, amazon-codewhisperer

When I open VS Code and start editing a file, I find I have to click the AWS icon in the sidebar before CodeWhisperer will enable it.

Is this the expected behavior?
Is there a way to have it enabled by default?

Comment: Might be a bug with the extension's [`activationEvents`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/activation-events). Consider also creating an issue ticket (first search if one exists) and linking us here to it.

Comment: can you share a link to the extension's marketplace page?

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=AmazonWebServices.aws-toolkit-vscode